# how to animate my android imageView to scale larger?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, animation

I thought using

```
    ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1, 1.1F, 1, 1);
    scaleAnimation.setDuration(DURATION);
    animation.addAnimation(scaleAnimation);
    mSwitchBg.startAnimation(animation);
```

but it make the image move, not scale larger.

I want it to stretch mSwitchBg (square) only on the left side (x axis)

for a moment, and then return to its original size.

Kind of resizing for a moment effect,

but only for on size.

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
new ScaleAnimation(fromXscale, toXscale, fromYscale, toYscale, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5);
```

The important thing is flag **Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF** and **0.5** — center of image